# React Native: Multiple fonts in one sentence

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

I need to use English with my local language into one sentence on React Native.

I have been through many posts, but seems there is no luck.

I am writing this for some answers or maybe some suggestions to workaround for this issue.

Example of what I am looking for is:

> Hello ពិភពលោក

I suppose to have `Hello` for a font, and `ពិភពលោក` for a font. P.S. the text is from DB.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

class Setting extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <Text style={ styles.customFont }>Hello ពិភពលោក</Text>
            </>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   customFont: {
      //// I want to have fallback font for English words (Aller Font, etc.)
      fontFamily: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'Siemreap' : 'Siemreap-Regular'
   }
});

export default Setting;
```

Comment: Can you please show us the code what you have so far? Easier to help like that, thanks!

Comment: react-native support nested text - https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#nested-text

Comment: @SDushan doing this is fine if i have the static text. But it's not a good idea from dynamic text or I will need to loop through the text and replace the English one with the nested text.

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: @AungMyintThein no, the fallback font seems impossible here.

Answer (score 0):

In React Native

> `Text` supports nesting, styling, and touch handling.

So, if I've understood your question, you're looking for something like this:

```
export default class Test extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Text>
          <Text style={styles.hello}>Hello </Text>
          <Text style={styles.name}>Michael</Text>
        </Text>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  hello: {
    fontFamily: 'Mishafi',
  },
  name: {
    fontFamily: 'Optima'
  },
});
```

Just replace the font style with what fits your case.
Let me know.

Comment: The fragment that you wrapped everything in should not be necessary.

Comment: @BenjaminGodlove you're right. Copy-pasted from the source and didn't pay attention

Comment: If it is static, it's not the matter. However, what I am looking to do is the dynamic text, which i don't really want to loop through each word and replace with nested text.

Comment: So your real problem is to recognize which text sections need to be displayed alternatively. Am I right now? Can I suggest you to improve your post in order to make it more comprehensible?

Comment: @BenjaminGodlove You would actually want them wrapped like that so that you would get proper word wrapping with multilined text. If they aren't nested under a single Text element, their multilines would begin at the beginning of their respective Text elements.