# Is it possible to use multiple fonts at the same time?

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to use 2 fonts at the same time for English and Arabic characters. Haven't been able to figure out how to do it :(

These are the fonts I'm trying to use.

Arabic: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Almarai?query=almarai

English: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Raleway?query=raleway

On web, it would be as simple as `font-family: Raleway, Almarai, sans-serif, Arial;`

If anyone knows how to do it, I would really appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 0):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Almarai&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Almarai&family=Raleway&display=swap');
body {
  font-family: 'Almarai', sans-serif;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World! is in this font style and I am too!</h1>
    <br> 
    <h2>I am styled as RALEWAY</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

Explanation: Google fonts provide rules to specify in `CSS` to import it as you do it also specifies how you use the font in this example I've demonstrated how. you use the `import("font link here")` to import the fonts or you could `link` them in the head. then you use the `font-family: 'font name here'` with an `element {}` to specify that the font is active. Then that element should be in that font.

Comment: I want to do it in react native, not a website.

Comment: Oh then I have no idea

Comment: Check out this it may sole your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60801227/react-native-multiple-fonts-in-one-sentence